# Am I able to see the EVM code?

Tags: evm

I want to try creating EVM, but it seems like it is not open sourced?
Are there any other way to find imitations, or to know EVM code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look for it there are tons of documentation and actual implementations and tutorials of how to do;

I'll link you couple, you do the rest.

**Building:**

- https://noxx3xxon.notion.site/Building-an-EVM-from-scratch-part-1-the-execution-context-c28ebb4200c94f6fb75948a5feffc686
- https://github.com/ethereum/evmone

**Understanding:**

- https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/
- https://noxx.substack.com/p/evm-deep-dives-the-path-to-shadowy?s=r
- https://medium.com/@eiki1212/explaining-ethereum-contract-abi-evm-bytecode-6afa6e917c3b

If you are looking for a 'poper EVM code' there isn't.
The EVM is pretty much just a VM plugged on a Blockchain.
There several implementations of EVM.
Here is the Geth implementation of an EVM:

- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/core/vm

Each Ethereum client has its own, using different language stacks.

Comment: I am looking for an original EVM Code. How can I find the original code that develops EVM? I found a lot of applied version of EVM, but that was not I am looking for. Do you have any ideas to search for the 'original EVM code?' Thank you

Comment: There isn't a proper 'EVM code', there a many implementations.
You'd find that on the githubs of opensource projects of Ethereum clients, or L2, or other Blockchains using an EVM.

I edited my answer to try to suit better  what you are looking for.